# Several errors and warnings for IronRuby / C# Windows Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, ironruby

I'm trying to call IronRuby code from a C# Windows Phone application, but when I try to build the project, I get several errors.

All the tutorials are outdated, so I'm doing my best. I installed the Windows Phone SDK, then installed IronRuby, then created a C# application for Windows Phone (there was no IronRuby template).

Visual Studio didn't know where to find the IronRuby DLLs, so I browsed and added them manually. All the tutorials say to use Silverlight, but there is no longer a Silverlight template for Windows Phone Visual Studio 2012, and the Silverlight DLL generates its own spurious errors.

**Code**

https://github.com/mcandre/ios7crypt/tree/master/WindowsPhone

**Trace**

```
Warning 1   Reference to type 'System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Core.dll', but it could not be found  c:\Program Files (x86)\IronRuby 1.1\Silverlight\bin\Microsoft.Scripting.dll IOS7Crypt
Warning 2   Reference to type 'System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Core.dll', but it could not be found  c:\Program Files (x86)\IronRuby 1.1\Silverlight\bin\Microsoft.Scripting.dll IOS7Crypt
Warning 3   Reference to type 'System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Core.dll', but it could not be found  c:\Program Files (x86)\IronRuby 1.1\Silverlight\bin\Microsoft.Scripting.dll IOS7Crypt
Warning 4   Reference to type 'System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Core.dll', but it could not be found  c:\Program Files (x86)\IronRuby 1.1\Silverlight\bin\Microsoft.Scripting.dll IOS7Crypt
Warning 5   Reference to type 'System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Core.dll', but it could not be found  c:\Program Files (x86)\IronRuby 1.1\Silverlight\bin\Microsoft.Scripting.dll IOS7Crypt
Error   6   Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported  C:\Users\andrew\Desktop\src\ios7crypt\WindowsPhone\IOS7Crypt\CSC    IOS7Crypt
Error   7   Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported  C:\Users\andrew\Desktop\src\ios7crypt\WindowsPhone\IOS7Crypt\CSC    IOS7Crypt
Error   8   Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference? C:\Users\andrew\Desktop\src\ios7crypt\WindowsPhone\IOS7Crypt\MainPage.xaml.cs   22  25  IOS7Crypt
Error   9   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptRuntime' to 'Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine'    C:\Users\andrew\Desktop\src\ios7crypt\WindowsPhone\IOS7Crypt\MainPage.xaml.cs   27  22  IOS7Crypt
Error   10  One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?    C:\Users\andrew\Desktop\src\ios7crypt\WindowsPhone\IOS7Crypt\MainPage.xaml.cs   33  27  IOS7Crypt
Error   11  One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?    C:\Users\andrew\Desktop\src\ios7crypt\WindowsPhone\IOS7Crypt\MainPage.xaml.cs   39  31  IOS7Crypt
```

**Specs**

- IronRuby 1.1
- Windows Phone Visual Studio 2012
- Windows 8 Professional x64
- MacBook Pro mid-2009

Comment: For the most recent versions of Windows and VS, you probably want to get and build IronRuby from source: https://github.com/ironlanguages/main

Comment: "In late 2010, Microsoft let go Jimmy Schementi, one of two remaining members of the core team and stopped funding the project." = The project was abandoned.

Comment: they actually open sourced the project and was picked up by the community microsoft also did thos with iron python and both are alive and well

Comment: @ChrisMcGrath No, IronRuby is essentially dead. There is zero support for DLR for Windows Phone, there are no IronRuby templates available, and every single online IronRuby tutorial is more than a year old.